# Makefiles - ar: *.a: No such file or directory.... but there is... it's right there

Tags: c, makefile

Trying to compile a friend's code - but he has included no Makefile, I build my own and am perplexed by an issue I've run into.

I think it's best I post the full contents of the Makefile below... I tried to keep it short!

```make
CFLAGS  = -Wall -pedantic
LFLAGS  =
CC      = gcc
RM      = /bin/rm -rf
AR      = ar rc
RANLIB  = ranlib

LIBRARY = const.a read.a descr.a

LIB_SRC = read.c futex.c testy.c

LIB_OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(LIB_SRC))

# pattern rule for object files
%.o: %.c
         $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

all: $(LIBRARY)

$(LIBRARY): $(LIB_OBJ)
        $(AR) $(LIBRARY) $(LIB_OBJ)
    $(RANLIB) $(LIBRARY)

clean:
    $(RM) $(LIBRARY) $(LIB_OBJ)

.PHONY: depend
depend:
        $(CFLAGS) -- $(LIB_SRC)  2>/dev/null
```

All of the files, const.h, read.h, and descr.h are in the directory in which I call make. Likewise for read.c, futex.c, and testy.c.

The files are entangled in various ways - if I need to show exactly the nature of these entanglements, I will do so.

I 'make' and the compiler alledges:

```
ar: read.a: No such file or directory
```

Is it not the case that read.a is supposed to be being produced? Of course it isn't there yet.

I've stared a while now and I feel like this must be something simple I am missing.

Comment: use `make V=1` next time ;)

Comment: `LFLAGS`? Are you using `lex` in your makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command:

```make
$(AR) $(LIBRARY) $(LIB_OBJ)
```

expands to this:

```bash
ar rc const.a read.a descr.a read.o futex.o testy.o
```

So when Make tries to build `const.a`, it tells `ar` to combine several files into `const.a`, starting with `read.a`, and `ar` complains that there's no such file. (Whether `ar` could do anything useful with `read.a` if it did exist is immaterial.)

It's not clear how you want Make to build those libraries, but this might be a step in the right direction:

```make
$(LIBRARY): $(LIB_OBJ)
    $(AR) $@ $(LIB_OBJ)
    $(RANLIB) $@
```

The [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$@` expands to the name of the target. You can use another one for the list of prerequisites (`$(LIB_OBJ)`), but let's try one new thing at a time.