# Nokogiri 1.13.3 Gem Install Failure Termux

Tags: nokogiri, termux

Here's the thing:
I used this [this script](https://github.com/gushmazuko/metasploit_in_termux/) trying to install Metasploit 6.

But Nokogiri can't find libm.so.6
I've tried ln -s /system/lib64/libm.so $PREFIX/lib/libm.so.6 to solve this problem,but it didn't work

After some troubleshooting,I think Nokogiri might not completely installed.

I'm not sure about which part I've missed.
pls help
Device:Realme X50

OS:Android 10

```
$ gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby -- --use-system-libraries
```

```
current directory: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.13.3/ext/nokogiri
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ruby -I /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r ./siteconf20220228-27822-xbzj3s.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking for whether -std=c99 is accepted as CFLAGS... yes
checking for whether -Wno-declaration-after-statement is accepted as CFLAGS... yes
checking for whether -g is accepted as CFLAGS... yes
checking for whether -Winline is accepted as CFLAGS... yes
checking for whether -Wmissing-noreturn is accepted as CFLAGS... yes
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
checking for libxml-2.0 using `pkg_config`... yes: ["-I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/libxml2 ", "-L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib", "-lxml2"]
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in -lexslt... yes
Using mini_portile version 2.8.0
---------- IMPORTANT NOTICE ----------
Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libgumbo-1.0.0-nokogiri.
Configuration options: --enable-shared --disable-static
[]
Copying gumbo-parser files into tmp/aarch64-unknown-linux-android/ports/libgumbo/1.0.0-nokogiri/gumbo-parser...
Running 'compile' for libgumbo 1.0.0-nokogiri... ERROR, review '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.13.3/ext/nokogiri/tmp/aarch64-unknown-linux-android/ports/libgumbo/1.0.0-nokogiri/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o foreign_attrs.o foreign_attrs.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o parser.o parser.c
parser.c:540:10: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'GumboInsertionMode' from 'void *' [-Wvoid-pointer-to-enum-cast]
  return (GumboInsertionMode) modes->data[(modes->length - 1)];
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o string_buffer.o string_buffer.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o string_piece.o string_piece.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o svg_attrs.o svg_attrs.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o svg_tags.o svg_tags.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o tag.o tag.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o tag_lookup.o tag_lookup.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o token_buffer.o token_buffer.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o tokenizer.o tokenizer.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o utf8.o utf8.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o util.o util.c
aarch64-linux-android-clang -fPIC -g -std=c99 -Wall   -c -o vector.o vector.c
ar rv libgumbo.a ascii.o attribute.o char_ref.o error.o foreign_attrs.o parser.o string_buffer.o string_piece.o svg_attrs.o svg_tags.o tag.o tag_lookup.o token_buffer.o tokenizer.o utf8.o util.o vector.o
make: ar: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:30: libgumbo.a] Error 127
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --prevent-strip
    --enable-system-libraries
    --disable-system-libraries
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-system-libraries
    --disable-system-libraries
    --use-system-libraries
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-z-dir
    --without-z-dir
    --with-z-include
    --without-z-include=${z-dir}/include
    --with-z-lib
    --without-z-lib=${z-dir}/lib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-libxml2-dir
    --without-libxml2-dir
    --with-libxml2-include
    --without-libxml2-include=${libxml2-dir}/include
    --with-libxml2-lib
    --without-libxml2-lib=${libxml2-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml2lib
    --without-libxml2lib
    --with-libxml-2.0-dir
    --without-libxml-2.0-dir
    --with-libxml-2.0-include
    --without-libxml-2.0-include=${libxml-2.0-dir}/include
    --with-libxml-2.0-lib
    --without-libxml-2.0-lib=${libxml-2.0-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-xsltlib
    --without-xsltlib
    --with-exslt-dir
    --without-exslt-dir
    --with-exslt-include
    --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
    --with-exslt-lib
    --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
    --with-exsltlib
    --without-exsltlib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.8.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:460:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.8.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:426:in `chdir'
    from /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.8.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:426:in `execute'
    from extconf.rb:968:in `compile'
    from /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.8.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:187:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:528:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:309:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:309:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:528:in `block in process_recipe'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:427:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:927:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/aarch64-linux-android/3.1.0/nokogiri-1.13.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: Same problem. Based on another thread it seems to be a problem with passing in the -L flag with make command, not exactly sure why yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446206/makefiles-ar-a-no-such-file-or-directory-but-there-is-its-right-th

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response.

I've had a similar issue while installing Rails.

I've fixed this by installing `pkg-config` and `binutils` like so:

`pkg install pkg-config binutils && gem install pkg-config`

If you get missing gumbo, install it by typing `pkg install gumbo-parser`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was also needed to install libxslt (`pkg install libxslt`)